# Cannot create a new computer account using the Windows active directory interface

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

When I attempt to create a new computer account using the Windows active directory interface by entering the new computer name and hitting next, I get a blank dialogue titled New-Object-Computer with no tabs and three nonfunctional buttons: back, finish, and cancel.  It can only be closed with the task manager.

The command

```
dsadd computer cn=newname,dc=mydomain,dc=local
```

succeeds, although I have to use the "find objects in Active Directory" button (Find: Computers In: Entire Directory) to find it and right click and move it to the Computers folder.

This is the only domain controller in a five person company, which has experienced infrequent changes and backups.  How should I proceed? I'm tempted to document and ignore the problem.

Comment: If you run a dcdiag on your server, does it report any errors?

Also, to get around the moving the computer to a different OU, you could put the correct OU, ie `"cn=newname,OU=computerContainer,OU=office,dc=mydomain,dc=local"`.

Do you have the same issue when adding users through Active Directory?

Comment: The only failure is `Starting test: Services
            IsmServ Service is stopped on [NAME]
         ......................... NAME failed test Services`  which I understand to be an optional service. Thank you for the correct OU. I have no problem adding users.

Answer (score 2):

The Active Directory Users and Computers interface is highly extensible and can be customized. It sounds like somebody might've messed around with it.

It sounds like the [Object Creation Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677917(v=vs.85).aspx) for computer objects isn't registered properly-- either in the registry on the DC or in your Directory's [displaySpecifiers container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675904(v=vs.85).aspx) or both.

Assuming you're using a US English Windows installation, what do you get back from a `dsquery * "CN=computer-Display,CN=409,CN=displaySpecifiers,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com" -attr createWizardExt` command (substituting in your domain for the `DC=domain,DC=com` portion). The stock `createWizardExt` value is `1,{D6D8C25A-4E83-11d2-8424-00C04FA372D4}`.

You can re-register the extension by reinstalling `%SystemRoot%\system32\adminpak.msi`.

Comment: `1,{D6D8C25A-4E83-11d2-8424-00C04FA372D4}`

was the value that dsquery returned.